# VS2010 add new file throws Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.DeferrableContent' threw an exception

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio 2010, when I right click a project and choose Add new item, the cursor blinks for a second but nothing happens.  If I go File > New > File, I get

Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.DeferrableContent' threw an exception

in a dialog box and can't add a new file.

I have Devexpress project templates and when Googling this error, see a few issues related to their WPF components.  I am also using Windows 8 release preview.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I am getting this error occasionally with VS2012.

Comment: No, I'm sure it's devexpress causing it. I know use my desktop for new projects and will reinstall vs on my laptop

Comment: Hrmmn I don't use dev express, nor many other add-ins. I will keep looking for a solution.

Answer (score 4):

I have **Windows azure tools for  Microsoft VisulStudio 2013- v2.2** and **Windows azure tools for  Microsoft lightswitch  VisulStudio 2013- v2.2**.

I uninstall only  Windows azure tools for **microsoft lightswitch vs 2013** .

It's working fine...

Answer (score 2):

I resolved it when checking the references of the project, for me it was Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word which had a different version that when I start coding this project. When loading the old references, everything went smoothly.

Comment: I'll have a look at this, thanks.  It's happening on practically every project I'm on but hopefully this will be it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the resolution was to UNINSTALL the `Windows Azure Tools for Visual Studio 2010` then I restarted the VS and the error gone straight away.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was to launch Visual Studio in safe mode and remove the related extensions installed by the Nuget Package for the Paradox Game engine.

Uninstalling Paradox via "Programs And Features" (which I did) leaves the extension itself still registered in Visual Studio, presumably causing  a hidden `NullReferenceException`.