# "Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.DeferrableContent' threw an exception": should I reinstall?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I suddenly get this error whenever I try to add a new item in VS 2013 Express:

> Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.DeferrableContent' threw an exception.

In addition, every .cs file is corrupt.  VS was working correctly yesterday.  I haven't made any configuration changes or installed any add-ons.

The discussions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12857294/vs2010-add-new-file-throws-set-property-system-windows-resourcedictionary-defer), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12857294/vs2010-add-new-file-throws-set-property-system-windows-resourcedictionary-defer) and [here](http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/2013/03/09/the-strange-case-of-quot-set-property-system-windows-resourcedictionary-deferrablecontent-threw-an-exception-quot/) recommended the following possible solutions:

- launch Visual Studio in Safe Mode
- run `devenv /resetuserdata` (in this case it's `wdexpress`), then restart the computer
- uninstall various tools and add-ins (I don't have any installed)

None of these solutions worked for me; the error still occurs under all conditions.

This happens whenever I try to add a class or reference or any other new item.

**Update:** I reinstalled Visual Studio and the problem still occurs.  However, it appears to be confined to a single project, as I can make a new project and add classes to it.  So maybe that project is corrupt somehow?

Comment: How are the .cs files corrupt?  Are they actually damaged, or is it just that they display weirdly?

Comment: @AnnL., when I open them, they all open in Notepad as a mess of characters like `êlÇPš—·õGÉ+sqÖY®ÓÇN­Ž9¯€8ï,?`.  The compiler also sees them as gibberish and throws a bunch of errors when I try to build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked out the most recent commit versions of the corrupted files, and that seems to have alleviated the problem.  I can add classes now.  Interestingly, when I was in Git Bash and tried to read one of the corrupt `.cs` files using `less`, it informed me that it was a binary file.